# Will opening/closing a webservice with an ActionFilter work correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In the past I've been using:

```
using (LoginServiceClient = new LoginServiceClient()) {
    //do stuff
    service.Close();
}
```

But now, I'm trying:

```
public class UseLoginService : ActionFilterAttribute {

    LoginServiceClient = new LoginServiceClient();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        filterContext.ActionParameters["service"] = service;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        service.Close();
    }
}

[UseLoginService]
public ActionResult myAction(LoginServiceClient service) {
    //service is accessible here
    return View();
}
```

Will this properly close/dispose of the service? Is there any way to tell? I'm concerned that by doing things this way I'm going to leave myself vulnerable to memory leaks.

Comment: Why rely on `ActionParameters` to inject dependency and not simple constructor injection?

Answer (score 0):

In a way, you are on a good path, but why did you decide to do it this way? First of all, you should use Dependency Injection. You can use NuGet to download Unity, Ninject, etc and have these services inject an object into your constructor. Second, what you are doing is poor-man's dependency injection. What happens if you exception is raised in one of your filters or there is an application failure? With your current implementation you have no way of controlling the resource cleanup.

To sum things up, you are reinventing the wheel. There is really no point unless you have some special request for doing it this way.

One more thing for the end. You don't really have to call `base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext)` because `ActionFilterAttribute` does not have anything implemented for this method. Basically it is an empty method body.

Comment: I guess my thought process was, "It would be great if I could just add a small tag to any method that needs to access the service, and just let it open and close the service for me". I've done some reading on dependency injection, and I'm not sure it can do that (but I see what you mean).